# How to create a resizable MessageDialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I create a `MessageDialog` that is resizable.

```java
Shell parentShell = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
MessageDialog.openInformation(parentShell, "title", "message");
```

The information dialog cannot be changed in size. How to make it resizable?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The message dialog opens in a new shell so the parent shell is not changed.

Comment: After executing, I have a new window but I cannot change it size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MessageDialog` is not meant to be resizable. If you really really want to make it resizeable, override the `getShellStyle()` method to return the desired style flags.

For example

```java
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog( shell,
                                          "title",
                                          null,
                                          "message",
                                          MessageDialog.INFORMATION,
                                          new String[] { IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL },
                                          0 ) 
{
  protected int getShellStyle() {
    return SWT.SHELL_TRIM;
  } 
};
```

will result in a resizable dialog with an information icon and min/max/close buttons.

Comment: Thanks for you response but there is no min/max/close

Comment: Only `SWT.SHEET` is accepted in the style parameter, all other styles are discarded.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for this hint. I've updated the answer with a hack to get a resizable message dialog. Mehdi, reconsider if you really want a resizeable message dialog. It's simple not designed to be resizable.